# Override language setting for some apps?

Tags: languages, locale

Is there a way to override the locale for some apps? My Android is set to German but I want, for example, all apps that don't have a proper translation to be in English - reading Google-translated stuff is horrible.

I know there's no native way, but maybe there's an app for it which I just couldn't find...

My device is running 4.1 and is rooted.

Comment: Perhaps you could use tasker to create a macro that will change the system language after which the desired app is launched. And then use that tasker shortcut to start the app. Not a tasker user, but there are a couple of Tasker Gurus who might lend a hand.

Comment: Some applications let you override the locale within the app... e.g., Plume and Handcent

Answer (score 5):

Somebody mentioned [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)? So here I am. And in fact you could do that with *Tasker* and the help of the [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin) Plugin:

1. Create a new task:

   - Plugins -> Secure Settings -> Locale Picker (pick your target locale here)
   - App -> Run (select the app to run)
   - Plugins -> Secure Settings -> Locale Picker (pick your original locale here)
2. Assign an icon to this task
3. On a free place of your homescreen, long press, add a tasker widget, pick this task

I did not test it, but it should work like this.

Comment: I tried it with Google Maps, and it doesn't work for me. When I launch the task from within Tasker Google Maps launches with the regular locale. When I create a shortcut in my homescreen and click it - nothing happens.
Any advice?

Comment: I never had that happen. There's no condition to it that could "fail". So when creating a shortcut as described, having the task assigned to, the task should be launched. Maybe a `logcat` can give a clue here?

Answer (score 1):

Since your device is rooted you can use [app settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings) which allows that and much more

Answer (score -1):

Changing system locale may cause a refresh of some tasks. This means more unwanted slowness of the device, more battery drain, and slow start of the original application. There are applications to do just that, but I think they need Root or do not work on every device or Android version.
The best solution would be changing our within app.

Comment: [citation needed] why it would cause noticeable battery drain