# Is it possible to run applications with different locales (languages)?

Tags: languages, locale

I want to run some applications in one language and the rest with the others. Specifically, I'd like to run maps in Russian (I really don't need names transliterated to Latin) and everything else in English (Russian translations are usually very poor and I just cannot understand what the app wants to tell me. English translations are usually good enough for me to understand).

I run stock android 4.2.2 on rooted Texet X-basic tm-4072. The [solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30414/override-language-setting-for-some-apps) involving Tasker does not apply for me because Google Play says Takser is not compatible with my phone. There was an [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wiirecords.localizedapps) for this, but now it's outdated and I don't know how to reach the author (he suggests to send the newer version to those who write to him).

In desktop Linux I'd simply run app with different LANG value, does something like that work for Android?

Comment: A hint concerning *Tasker*: You can grab the `.apk` from their website and see whether it installs nevertheless. (and before you ask: no idea for the rest, sorry – at least not if the apps don't support it by themselves: some apps let you chose the language to use, and just default to "system")

Comment: According to the recent announcements Android 13 will be able to change the locale/language for every app.

Answer (score 1):

[This module](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings) for Xposed Framework should do the trick if your device is rooted.

1. Install [Xposed Installer](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer).
2. Run Xposed Installer and use it to install Xposed Framework. It's a two-tap operation followed by a reboot.
3. Find the App Settings module in Xposed Installer, install and enable it. Reboot device.
4. Click the module in Xposed Installer to show its GUI. You'll be presented with available features, including changing app locale.

Comment: This way does not seem to work for me: [enabled](https://s3.amazonaws.com/pushbullet-uploads/ujxVqS0Lsk0-Z5tk5XGm61UI5fZi97iMfzYcxSZlbLrB/Screenshot_2014-08-06-16-46-09.png), [settings changed](https://s3.amazonaws.com/pushbullet-uploads/ujxVqS0Lsk0-pLpr3q8BmwwostoYgLAUDsPQvJHQGuj0/Screenshot_2014-08-06-16-47-38.png) but still [english](https://s3.amazonaws.com/pushbullet-uploads/ujxVqS0Lsk0-p3BAbrRDtupxm8zk47eNtuxicfvlmtD5/Screenshot_2014-08-06-16-49-15.png)

Answer (score 1):

Locales are programmed on a per app basis,

For example, if i developed an application with hard coded string characters in English, the hard coded characters will always be in that language...

It requires translations, string's of characters to replace per locale...

If you are sure it supports the language then it is hypothetically possible, however the developer defines the the default language...

You can manipulate or MOD the APK with something like APK Editor or APK Tool to set Russian as the default locale in the application.

The problem i think you are having is that your specific app needs an update to one with a larger selection of translations.

Answer (score 0):

This app [Xposed App Locale](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zhangfx.xposed.applocale&hl=en) helped me to change locale per application.

Comment: It's definitely worth adding that, like any Xposed module, this suggestion requires [tag:root-access] and involves big modifications to the Android framework on your phone.