# Change language of an Andoird app?

Tags: languages

Some Android apps allows users to change language in setting,
but some apps fixes the app language to the system language.
If the app does not allow the user to change language, can I use the different language from the system default language?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to run applications with different locales (languages)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/78899/is-it-possible-to-run-applications-with-different-locales-languages)

Comment: Translations are added by the app developer for every language they want to support in their app. If the developer didn't translate the English strings to any other language, app won't change locale when changed in device Settings.

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a way to accomplish this without rooting or using any virtual-machine-like (such as Parallel Space).

Comment: Translations provided by the app developer is sometimes does not make sense since they sometime use machine translation.