# Is there a 'first'or 'original' language in the app?

Tags: languages

Many Android apps supports multiple language so that it follows the system default language or users can select language from the setting.
Sometime the translation quality is poor, so I would like to see the 'original' version of the app, not the translated version.
Is there such as option?

Comment: See this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change language of an Android app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/229044/change-language-of-an-andoird-app)